# Did I answer this interview challenge right? (Checking for valid binary tree in C#)

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am a beginner to C#. Let me know if I did this interview question correctly (The interview is over, so don't think you're helping me cheat or anything).

The prompt was

> Write a function to determine whether a given binary tree of distinct
>   integers is a valid binary search tree. Assume that each node contains
>   a pointer to its left child, a pointer to its right child, and an
>   integer, but not a pointer to its parent.  You may use any language
>   you like.However, if your language already has libraries, you may not
>   use those libraries.

```
public class node
{
    node left { get; set; }
    node right { get; set; }
    int val;
}
```

(Is the above, that I wrote, correct for how to create a node based on the prompt? Because `node` is a `class`, my `left` and `right` are references, i.e. copies of memory addresses, to `node`s. Right?)

```
bool IsValidBT ( node N, HashSet<int> H ) 
{
    // function is initially called on the root node with an
    // empty HashSet<int> and is recursively called on 
    // the children, checking for any repeats in which case
    // the tree would be invalid

    if (  H.Contains(N.val) ) return false;
    else  H.Add(N.val);

   if ( left != null && !IsValidBT(left) ) return false;
   if ( right != null && !IsValidBT(right) ) return false; 

   return true; // if made it here, still valid  
}
```

Ok, the prompt said no using libraries, but I assume they mean no using any libraries that provide 1-line solutions. Of course I'm going to need the standard library at least. But is there anything wrong with the above logic? Is there any way a binary tree can be invalid unless it somehow contains repeated values?

Comment: I would assume that condition for a binary search tree to be valid is that the value of left node is always smaller than the right node. It also needs distinct entries but that was kind of assumed in the question.

Comment: You were to check for a `valid binary SEARCH tree` - consider making the title reflect this. What _does_ make a binary tree a _valid_ BST?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree - **Verification** section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems possibly more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com. But it's simple enough to answer, so…

Bottom line, no. You did not answer the question correctly. The most obvious flaw is that the code won't compile. You've declared a method `IsValidBT(node, HashSet<int>)`, but then when you call it, you only pass one argument. That can't work.

It is also not clear that you understood the question correctly. You seem to be concerned as to whether there are repeats in the data. But **a)** it is not clear from the prompt that that would even be disallowed, and **b)** the more obvious reason a binary tree would be invalid is if the data was not organized in an ordered way (e.g. if a number to the left of a parent was greater than the parent's value).

As noted in the comments, you can find a classical implementation of a validation (or verification) of a binary search tree on Wikipedia: [Binary search tree - Verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Verification). A C# version of the C++ algorithm shown there, using your `node` data structure, might look something like this:

```
bool IsBST(node n, int minKey, int maxKey)
{
    if (n == null) return true;

    // Assumes that equal valued children are placed to the left
    if (n.val <= minKey || n.val > maxKey) return false;

    return IsBST(n.left, minKey, n.val) && IsBST(n.right, n.val, maxKey);
}
```

Called like so:

```
IsBST(rootNode, int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
```